# AngularJS ui.router. Как убрать кэширование при роутинге?

Tags: шаблоны, кэширование, angular-ui-router

Есть код:

```
angular
    .module('responseRouter',['ui.router']).
config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('response/detail/:responseId', {
            url: "/response/detail/:responseId",
            cache: false,
            reload: true,
            templateUrl: function($stateParams){
                return '/_teacher/_admin/response/view/id/'+$stateParams.responseId
            }
        })
});
```

Сначала посещаем эту страницу, потом переходим на вторую, на второй делаем изменение данных для первой и перенаправляем на первую после изменения этих данных таким способом:

```
 $state.go("response/detail/:responseId", {responseId:responseId}, {reload: true});
```

Данные на первой страничке остаются старые до обновления. Как удалить этот кэш?

Пытался решить проблему таким способом:

```
angular
        .module('responseRouter',['ui.router'])
.run(['$rootScope', '$templateCache','$state',
            function ($rootScope, $templateCache, $state) {
                    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
                            if (typeof($state.current) !== 'undefined'){
                                    $templateCache.removeAll();
//$templateCache.remove($state.current.templateUrl); - для ui router не работает, работает как я понимаю для встроенного маршрутизатора 
                            }
                    });
            }]);
```

$templateCache.removeAll(); - удалять весь кэш наверно не правильно и затратно, хотел бы удалять при смене стэйта кэш предыдущего стэйта. Использую для этого $stateChangeStart - так как стэйтов много и при каждой смене нужно чистить данные или же обновлять их.
Что посоветуете в данной ситуации?(нужно загружать странички по стэйту не из кэша)

Comment: что именно кэшируется-то? какие данные меняются? _templateCache_ - как ни странно хранит именно шаблоны

Comment: Это html разбавленный вставками php кода. Понимаю что лучше все хранить в модели ангуляра, но тут нужно было переписывать страницу по-быстрому. Данные с сервера как раз и оставались старые(те что подтягивал php). Решили проблему способом $templateCache.remove(url), где url ссылка(екшн) по которой подтягиваются данные с сервера

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с точно такой же проблемой. Фиксил таким образом:

```
   var imageUrl = $rootScope.site + $rootScope.avatar;
   $scope.decachedimageUrl = imageUrl + '?decache=' + Math.random();
```

UPD: солюшн для чисел или текста на примере даты:

```
  $scope.rma = {};
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
  var dateVal = num + "-" + $rootScope.date; // Склеиваем случайное число с входящей датой
  console.log('date val :');
  console.log(dateVal);
  var datePartials = dateVal.split("-"); // Делим что получилось на части
  $scope.rma.purchaseDate = datePartials[1]; // В этом примере часть с индексом [1]  - год
  var newDate = new Date().getFullYear(); // Смотрим какой сейчас год
  $scope.rma.purchaseDate = newDate - datePartials[1]; // Получаем число лет, разницу между входящей датой и текущей. 
                                        //Например количество полных лет пользователя.
```